Why my mysqldumps are corrupted?
Every night laravel scheduler runs "mysqldump -h $dbHost -u $dbUsername -p$dbPassword $dbDatabase > $path/$filename" command through exec() functon.
And sometimes the dump is corrupted in some random place:
Good dump looks like that:
LOCK TABLES `action_categories_link` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `action_categories_link` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `action_categories_link` VALUES (1,1,1),(10,2,1),(15,3,2);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `action_categories_link` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

And the bad one:
LOCK TABLES `action_categories_link` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `action_categories_link` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `action_categories_link` VALUES (1,1,1),(10,2,1),(15,3,/*!4/*40000 ALTER TABLE `action_categories_link` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

Also, I have seen this line:
LOCKLOCK TABLES `action_categories` WRITE;

Can't I run a dump while the application is running? Typical dump size is almost 2GB, but those errors appear from the very beginning. Some dumps are not corrupted, so I have no clue.
Dumping on the same linux-server as db, w/o docker. MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.29

have you thought about replcation, and making the backup from there

Perhaps your "laravel scheduler", whatever that is, launches more than one dump at the same time?

I would guess the laravel scheduler is running more than one dump simultaneously, overwriting the same dump file.

If you want to use mysqldump on a database while it is in use, add the --single-transaction option. If your tables are InnoDB, this allows the dump to avoid locking tables. Read the MySQL manual on mysqldump for more information.

As @mustaccio said:

Perhaps your "laravel scheduler", whatever that is, launches more than one dump at the same time?

My dev application was running backup at the same time as my prod application to the same file, resulting a corrupted dump
